# Running script from the editor and from a menu in the sheet is producing different results, is this a bug?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote a Sheets/Drive/Docs script for my company and it's been working fine since. Today, I was adding a new feature and ran it from the Apps Script editor and got unexpected results.

Until today, IIRC running it from the editor or the custom menu my script creates produced the same result.

I wrote a simple test function to see what was going on:

```js
const onOpen = (e) => {
    const menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Test");
    menu.addItem("test", "test");
    menu.addToUi();
}

const test = () => {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    const selection = sheet.getSelection().getActiveRange();
    Logger.log(selection.getA1Notation())
}
```

If I make a random selection, say B3:C4, when the `test` function is run from the Test->test menu in the sheet, I get `B3:C4` as expected, but when run from the editor, I always get `A1`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not able to duplicate your error.  If I select random cell and run test from the script editor it gives me the A1 notation of the selected cells.

Comment: So wait, if you select say D1:D3, and run from the script editor, do you get "D1:D3" or do you get "A1"?

Comment: Yes I get D1:D3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a function in the Script Editor window, the function will only be able to get the active sheet and range when the Script Editor window is associated with the spreadsheet window.

The two windows are automatically associated when the Script Editor is opened through **Extensions > Apps Script**. If you reload the Script Editor window, it will no longer be associated with the spreadsheet window. The same happens if you open the Script Editor window through a bookmark or some such means other than the **Extensions > Apps Script** menu command.

When the Script Editor window is not associated with the spreadsheet window, `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()` will always get the sheet that appears first in the tab bar, and `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange()` will always get cell `A1` on that sheet, rather than the sheet and range the user at the keyboard currently has selected.

To make it work, close the Script Editor window and reopen it through **Extensions > Apps Script**.

Comment: That explains it! Thank you so much for your reply. I hope this will help others that encounter this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my test case run from script editor.

[image]

**Code.gs**

```
const test = () => {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    const selection = sheet.getSelection().getActiveRange();
    Logger.log(selection.getA1Notation())
}
```

**Execution log**

```
9:47:26 AM  Notice  Execution started
9:47:27 AM  Info    B4:B8
9:47:27 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```